# Coin change with fixed denominations with duplicate values

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

Suppose I have $\{1, 1\} \{2, 2, 2\} \{5\} \{10\}$ coins.

How many ways I can get 15 by adding coins?

If I use DP then it counts 7, because $\{1+2+2+10\} \{1+2+2+10\} \{1+2+2+10\} \{1+2+2+10\} \{1+2+2+10\} \{1+2+2+10\}$ and $\{10 + 5\}$. But actual result is $\{1+2+2+10\}$ and $\{10 + 5\}$. How do I solve efficiently?

Now I able to figure out the solution. I have to find integral solutions of equation $x+2y+5z+10m=15$ with constraints $x <= 2$, $y <= 3$, $z <= 1$ and $m <= 1$. Now how to do that?

Comment: dynamic programming https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Comment: Your DP answer repeats combinations, suggesting that you are thinking of the coins with the same value as different from each other. The "actual result" suggests they are the same. And you're missing combinations with $(1,1)$ replacing a $(2)$. Please edit the question to clarify. That said, I suspect there is no good algorithm to count what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to the already given answer showing that calculating the coefficient is not that cumbersome. We use the *coefficient of* operator  $[x^n]$ to  denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a polynomial.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{15}]}&\color{blue}{(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^5)(1+x^{10})}\\
> &=[x^{15}](1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15})(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)\tag{1}\\
> &=\left([x^{15}]+[x^{10}]+[x^5]+[x^0]\right)(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^5]+[x^0]\right)(\color{blue}{1}+x+x^2)(\color{blue}{1}+x^2+x^4+x^6)\tag{3}\\
> &=1+[x^5](1+\color{blue}{x}+x^2)(1+x^2+\color{blue}{x^4}+x^6)\tag{4}\\
> &=1+1\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply  out the terms with the highest powers which is convenient as we will see in step (3).
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (3) we can skip $[x^{15}]$ and $[x^{10}]$ since they do not contribute as   the highest power of $x$  is $8$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^0$.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^5$.

Comment: but last 6 means 1, actually it should result 2

Comment: @DebasisJana: Ok, I see. From your example I thought you wanted to distinguish them.

Comment: But in terms of computation how do I solve it? If I do polynomial multiplication then it will be a brute force approach. What is the efficient algorithm?

Comment: @DebasisJana: As long as there is a moderate number of terms involved as in this example the brute force approach is presumably the most appropriate. Somewhat more sophisticated techniques could implement a cut off of branches as it done in the calculation from step 2 to step 3.

Comment: Good point (+1).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function for the number of solutions in integers to
$$x_1 + 2x_2 + 5 x_3 + 10 x_4 = r$$
subject to $0 \le x_1 \le 2$, $0 \le x_2 \le 3$, $0 \le x_3 \le 1$ and $0 \le x_4 \le 1$ is
$$f(x) = (1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^5)(1+x^{10})$$
The answer to your problem is the coefficient of $x^{15}$ when this polynomial is expanded, which is $2$.  I used a computer algebra system for the expansion.  Expanding the polynomial by hand is possible, but tedious unless you can find a shortcut.

Another approach is to observe that using only coins of denomination 1, 2, or 5, the largest amount you can make is 13, so you must use one coin of denomination 10 if the total is to be 15.  That leaves an amount of 5 to be made up from coins of denomination 1, 2, or 5.  There aren't many cases to consider, and you can probably see that the only possibilities are 5 and 1+2+2.

Comment: Marcus Scheuer's solution shows that pencil and paper expansion of the generating function to find the coefficient of $x^{15}$ is not tedious, if approached correctly.